# Where does this variable come from in Codeigniter? And are there any more?

Tags: php, codeigniter

In the default Codeigniter installation there is the "welcome" controller which has a "index" action which loads the "welcome" view. This works as expected.

However, upon inspecting the "welcome" view I can see this variable in the footer.

```
<p class="footer">Page rendered in <strong>{elapsed_time}</strong> seconds</p>
```

From what I understand the variable `{elapsed_time}` is an example of using the built in template parser with text representations instead of using PHP short tags to echo variables.

But inside the "welcome" controller the only lines in the "index" action are these.

```
$this->load->view('welcome');
```

And it doesn't pass `$data['elapsed_time']='xxx';` which means that I can't figure out where the variable `elapsed_time` is coming from!

My question is this.

Where does `elapsed_time` get defined? Is it built into the template parser class (and therefore available to be used without first defining it)? If so, where is a list of these other pre-defined varaibles? I would like to know what else I have access to as had I known that `elapsed_time` was available to me it would have been very useful. Does anyone have a list of the template parser pre-defined variables?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

elapsed_time defined output class. this class is initialized automatically by CodeIgniter.

more info [here](http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/libraries/output.html)

Comment: So it looks like I have access to both `{elapsed_time}` and `{memory_usage}` inside my views... Thanks for the advice!

Answer (score 3):

CI will replace the string of "`{elapsed_time}`" in the final output string with actual "total_execution_time ". You can check it in **system/core/Output.php Line 366** of **v213**